# Pattern syntax %.3: man/libfoo.man in Automake with different base name

Tags: linux, makefile, gnu-make, automake

I wrote a library `libfoo` providing functions `bar` and `baz`.
I want the user to be able to find the same man-page (from `mans/libfoo.man`) when they call `man libfoo`, `man bar` and `man baz` (Similar to `man fprintf`, `man sprintf` all pointing to the same page.)

My current setup has the files `mans/libfoo.man` and `Makefile.am`

To 'tell' automake that I want to end up with the three man-pages I specified the `dist_man3_MANS` variable.

Makefile.am:

```
dist_man3_MANS = mans/libfoo.3 mans/bar.3 mans/baz.3
```

Coming from GNU make, I thought I could just write

```
%.3: mans/libfoo.man
    ln -S libfoo.man $@
```

to create links temporarily and then let Automake install those accordingly, but Automake errors out with `Makefile.am:115: warning: '%'-style pattern rules are a GNU make extension`. I want to do it properly and take this warning seriously by not relying on GNU Make to be as portable as possible.

[The Automake manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/html_node/Suffixes.html) suggests to add a target

```
.man.3:
    $(LN_S) $^ $@
```

but that just tells Automake that `xx.man` can be compiled to `xx.3`, requiring the base name to be the same. I don't want to carry around those `xx.man` files, so this approach does not work.

I could hack it in with putting a rule

```
dist_man3_MANS = mans/libfoo.3 mans/bar.3 mans/baz.3

$(dist_man3_MANS): mans/libfoo.man
    $(LN_S) libfoo.man $@
```

but that seems like a dirty hack, because I am not giving it a recipe to compile `.man` to `.3`, but rather say: "Hey, you can create those files with this rule", which for this case may work coincidental.

Comment: There is no way to write an implicit rule that will create targets in a different directory than the prerequisite (or vice versa) using POSIX standard makefiles.  You either have to use GNU extensions, or you have to write explicit rules for all these targets.  I'm not sure why you are not willing to write explicit rules or why you call it a "dirty hack"; it seems fine to me.  I don't understand your objection to it.

Comment: As you point out the directories, how would I do it, if a(nother) `Makefile.am` would be in the `mans` directory? I mean the target is in `mans/` and the prerequisite is, too. Re 'dirty hack', I'll try to explain it differently then: I want to tell Automake how to bake cake, not tell it how bake banana cake and tell it how to bake chocolate cake and carrot cake individually (just seems wrong to me in the mentality of `make`)

Comment: If both target and prerequisite are in the same directory you can use a suffix rule, which is part of POSIX make: https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Suffix-Rules.html  Maybe I'm just not a picky cake eater, but I see nothing wrong with writing explicit rules in makefiles.  I do it all the time.

Answer (score 0):

I would follow the example from the Automake info page section *Extending Automake Rules* and do something along the lines of

```
LIBFOO_MAN_ALIASES = bar baz

install-data-hook:
    set -e; \
    cd $(DESTDIR)$(man3dir) && \
    for manalias in $(LIBFOO_MAN_ALIASES); do \
        $(LN_S) libfoo.3 $${manalias}.3; \
    done

uninstall-hook:
    cd $(DESTDIR)$(man3dir) && \
    for manalias in $(LIBFOO_MAN_ALIASES); do \
        rm -f $${manalias}.3; \
    done
```

relying on `AC_PROG_LN_S` to make sure that `$(LN_S)` does something reasonable for the system (symlink, hardlink, copy) to create a file name which can be `open(2)`ed and read.

FTR, I have just taken a look at three different systems' man pages and found them using three different methods to make the fprintf(3) man page show the same man page as printf(3) does:

- Debian 10 uses symlinks
- Fedora 35 uses a /usr/share/man/man3/fprintf.3 file containing `.so man3/printf.3` (while some other man pages use symlinks to achieve the same effect)
- FreeBSD 13 uses hardlinks, and `find /usr/share/man -type l` does not find any symlinks on my relatively clean system. However, manually testing both symlinks and the `.so man3/printf.3` method suggests that FreeBSD `man(1)` does not treat symlinks in any special way and therefore opens the symlinked man page, and it also interprets the `.so` command just like Fedora 35's `man(1)` does.

I do not know how portable each of those methods is. Each of these three methods could set up on `make install` by using an appropriate `install-data-hook`, but any man file which can be opened using `open(2)` appears to be work, and therefore `$(LN_S)` looks like a good bet.